# How to show selected items list with the ability to remove them

Tags: multi-selection, drop-down-list, tags, deletion

I have the current design of items selection like this:

[image]

A user can select multiple items from different tag types. The checkboxes allow multiple selections of items from the list. When Tag type 1 is selected from the spinner, one list is shown and a user can select several items from it. When switched to Tag type 2 - another list is shown and in the same way a user can select also several items from this list.

I need to show her the list of currently selected items and provide the ability to remove some. I have two ideas how to do that:

1. Use tabs
2. Use simple text field

Here is the first option:

[image]

Here is the second option:

[image]

Which is more suitable to my task? Maybe there's something that I haven't through of.

Comment: What are the checkboxes for? Assuming "List item x" is used for this as an example, how is that name being defined?

Comment: @jazZRo, the checkboxes allow multiple selections of items from the list. When `Tag type 1` is selected from the spinner, one list is shown and a user can select several items from it. When switched to `Tag type 2` - another list is shown and in the same way a user can select also several items from this list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe you can add it to the question because that is somewhat essential to know.

Comment: I think your interface is too complicated. Can you split the delete task to a per-list basis? I.e. the user can only delete items from the currently selected list. Or asking the other way around: **Why do you think users would like to select items for deletion, then browse a different list while still retaining the previous' list's deleting selection?**

Comment: I removed the [tag:android] tag because it really isn't specific to that OS and updated the question with more relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you almost have figured out your answer.
From a usability perspective you have to show **what the user can reach** *(tag names)* but also **provide feedback** that he/she can select list items from others tag types.

I think a combination of both would be great on large screens (a tabular table, and a space "selected items").
But on mobile we don't have so much space so **you could use a *selected items heading* (the feedback) followed by *tabs* (the "what can I reach")**.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3l3hp.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

What is your opinion?

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand what's inside `0 selected items` field on the right screen?

Comment: @Maximus I edited the above wireframe. If you can't see it, the first mobile has "0 selected items" and the second mobile has "5 selected items" (two from tab1 and three from tab2). With this text, we add an indicator that when the user switch tabs, his selections remain selected.